# Google maps: overlay selection-end event

Tags: google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

In my application I have to draw some polygons on google map. The polygons are editable.

When I click on a polygon with large number of points, it takes very long time to be selected.
That is why i want the user to see a loading message when the selection is going on.

The problem is, i dont know when the selection is done and i have got the control back.

Is there any event like `selectionEnd` for polygon (or `MVCObject`)?

Comment: will the idle event work?

Comment: @geocodezip: No, we tried idle already.

Comment: Editing large shapes is a painful experience. We often crashed the browser when trying to do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647124/how-can-i-edit-large-polygons-without-crashing-the-browser How did you end up handling this problem?