# How can I edit large polygons without crashing the browser?

Tags: memory-management, google-maps-api-3

I have a polygon that consists of a single path with 12.5K points. When I mark it as editable `shape.setEditable(true)`, the memory usage for my tab skyrockets to about 800M until the browser kills the process.

I've noticed that marking a smaller polygon, with only about 1K points, as editable takes a while to process and eats up about 100M of memory. I figure the time is spent calculating midpoints and allocating objects and event handlers for all of the nodes and midpoints.

Is there a way to edit large shapes without using so much memory?

Google Map Maker had (has?) [a related problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-mapmaker/B47gLiRc6iI) in which someone suggested marking a specific portion of the polygon for editing. I suppose I'll try that if there's no way around the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the [gmaps-large-polygons](https://github.com/openplacedatabase/gmaps-large-polygons) library to solve this problem. When polygons are marked as editable, it splits the ppolygon's paths into line segments of a given size and only allows you to edit one segment at a time. This prevents you from using up all your memory by having thousands of edit vertices rendered for the whole polygon at once.

Comment: This was a pure genius approach. I have been looking for ways to improve performance of 1,000+ point polygons and invested some time into ways of doing my own canvas drawing. Your solution was brilliant!